# Netlify takes a refresh to update

Tags: gatsby, netlify

Running a Gatsby site one Netlify. Every time A user visits the site it shows a cached version and requires a refresh to get the latest version. The version shown can be months old depending on the last to the user (maybe browser) visited the site. After one refresh it shows the update version.

Is this a Gatsby or Netlify issue? Can I set a TTL on a server?

[site](https://marcusmth.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If your website has a service worker installed, it caches the website in your browser and serves the cached version next time you visit the website.

You could hook into the Gatsby Browser API to write a function that checks for service worker updates on first load and prompts the user to reload the page for the latest version.
For example, in `gatsby-browser.js`

```js
export const onServiceWorkerUpdateReady = () => {
  const answer = window.confirm(
    "This website has been updated. Reload to display the latest version?"
  );
  if (answer === true) {
    window.location.reload();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a detailed discussion in [this Netlify thread](https://community.netlify.com/t/cache-issue-on-netlify/8238/18).

There's nothing to do in the Gatsby side, it's related to [how to handle the service workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle).

In addition, one easy thing you can do to force a cache removal through the Netlify dashboard or `netlify-cli` when deploying, this can be achieved through a [file-based configuration](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/) or Netlify's dashboard.

The cache directory is under `/opt/build/cache`, so you'll need to remove it by adding a custom command. Take a look at the [sample in the `netlify.toml`](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/#sample-file) based configuration.

Comment: In the Netlify dashboard I found the button to clear the cache. Where are the settings to clear the cache on every deploy? thx

Comment: You'll need to add a custom server action, like `rm -rf /opt/build/cache` in your `netlify.toml` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this depends on your setup really. But yes this is the default behaviour of Gatsby-plugin-offline. I made a small function included in gatsby-browser.js that checks for updates every time the user navigates between pages. This really is a very small check and shouldn't negatively affect pagespeed in any way:

```
export const onRouteUpdate = () => {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(reg => {
  reg.update()
  })
}

export const onServiceWorkerUpdateReady = () => {
  console.log("update available to PWA");
  localStorage.setItem('update-ready', 'true');
  document.querySelector('.updateBanner').style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector('.updateBanner').style.opacity = "1";
  };
```

(Opacity is only included to be able to make a nice "fade-in effect of the banner)

The "update banner" hidden on my page is then implemented in the layout of my page and includes a "page reload button" - really just a function that runs window.location.reload(true);

I then call:

```
localStorage.setItem('update-ready', 'false');
```

I also implement a small "useEffect" in the banner that checks if update ready is set to "true" in local storage. This way the update banner will be visible consistently on the page until the button is pressed:

```
const updateReady = window.localStorage.getItem('update-ready');
  if(updateReady === 'true') {
  document.querySelector('.updateBanner').style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector('.updateBanner').style.opacity = "1";
```